# How to grant read access to this resource in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to generate a token with the smallest amount of privileges from here:

```
https://{MyCompany}.visualstudio.com/_usersSettings/tokens
```

I want to grant access to this API endpoint:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/resource%20usage/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0
```

and have so far given my token permission to read the builds:

[image]

but i'm still getting unauthorised.

My question is, what permission do i need to grant to get at this data?

Thanks

Comment: i think you need "Agent Pools": "Read" for this